Using 3d graphics to make presentations of game logics and objects among role playing characters?
The idea is about while opening games to give the players the feeling of having the full control of vision and the ability to observe the conditions of objects in the room and on the maps, which are need for gaming.
I have to struggle sometimes to reveal the secrets of objects and creatures by talking about them and this gives me the emotional depression, because nobody knows except me about the details. Obviously, they could be realized from the players, too if they would have a chance to make an idea about these secret details by just gazing at them. I would suggest to make rooms and creatures reasonable in fantasy, minding the players' conditions. This means, making secrets in 3d graphics. A group of six players divided in two subgroups and one DM, for example. Every subgroup will get one tablet and the DM will control their tablets by his own. Every time when DM describes a new scene, it will be a great help to support his/her words. It will happen like a slide-show. Every scene will be presented by these 3d graphics on tablets.
I know, the traditional FRP might not take this for realizable, but time is changing. In the past time, there were no computers but pen and paper. I think the men at those times, if they had a chance to make things better and easier, they would mean this technological support for serious.
Can tablets be used for FRP gaming to illustrate the secrets among role playing characters?

Welcome! :) Small bugbear. The title is an open question which invites answers that discuss the value of using 3D graphics or not. But your question about the tablets at the end is a yes or no closed question - which kind of asks to support the position that you'd like something practical so as to not describe things in detail It would be nice if the second question was not closed and invited more than an answer rather than a yes or, to discuss the advantages/disadvantages and to include lived experience of GMs using this method - or not and, if not, why not.

Graphics have been used in RPGs since the beginning

The above is from Tomb of Horrors ©1978 TSR Inc.
In addition, people use computer graphics, videos, virtual tabletops, and physical props. Some of those will work on a tablet.
If you have the skills, you can do it yourself. If you don't, you can learn them or buy pre-made stuff.
